# How to show 2 queries with 'group by' as one in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I'm trying to combine the results of two queries with two equal columns (the queries have 2 `Group by`).

I've tried with `Union` and `Join` statements but do not give the desired result or I have used them wrong

Query #1:

```
SELECT 
    COD_RCA, COD_MATERIAL, SUM(TM_SALIDA) AS INCLUIR
FROM 
    BASE_MESES
WHERE  
    PONDERADA = 'INCLUIR' AND ANO = '2017' AND MES = 'DEZ' 
GROUP BY 
    COD_RCA, COD_MATERIAL
```

[image]

Query #2:

```
SELECT 
    COD_RCA, COD_MATERIAL, SUM(REAL_TM) AS TOTAL
FROM 
    BASE_MESES
WHERE 
    ANO = '2017' AND MES = 'DEZ' 
GROUP BY 
    COD_RCA, COD_MATERIAL
```

[image]

I need something like this:

[image]

where `COD_RCA` and `COD_MATERIAL` are the relation between query #1 and query #2.

Thank you

Comment: Please insert your samples as `formatted text`. The mayority of us won't click on any links.

Comment: First create a temporary table in which you insert the first select.
After that update that table with the secondd select based on COD_RCA and COD_MATERIAL relations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COD_RCA,COD_MATERIAL
    ,SUM(IIF( PONDERADA='INCLUIR',TM_SALIDA,0)) AS INCLUIR
    ,SUM(REAL_TM) AS TOTAL
FROM BASE_MESES
WHERE ANO ='2017' AND MES='DEZ' 
GROUP BY COD_RCA, COD_MATERIAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaking, your two queries can be largely factorized, as there are very close one from the other. You just need a CASE to make a conditional sum to compute the « INCLUIR » result column.

```
SELECT 
    COD_RCA,
    COD_MATERIAL,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN PONDERADA='INCLUIR' THEN TM_SALID ELSE 0 END
    ) AS INCLUIR,
    SUM(REAL_TM) AS TOTAL
FROM BASE_MESES
WHERE 
    ANO ='2017' 
    AND MES='DEZ' 
GROUP BY 
    COD_RCA, 
    COD_MATERIAL
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (but best solution is solition of Lukasz Szozda):

```
With quer1 as 
(
SELECT COD_RCA, COD_MATERIAL,SUM(TM_SALIDA) AS INCLUIR
FROM BASE_MESES
WHERE  PONDERADA='INCLUIR' AND ANO ='2017' AND MES='DEZ' 
GROUP BY COD_RCA, COD_MATERIAL
),
Query2 as (
SELECT COD_RCA, COD_MATERIAL,SUM(REAL_TM) AS TOTAL
FROM BASE_MESES
WHERE ANO ='2017' AND MES='DEZ' 
GROUP BY COD_RCA, COD_MATERIAL
)
select isnull(f1.COD_RCA, f2.COD_RCA) COD_RCA, 
isnull(f1.COD_MATERIAL, f2.COD_MATERIAL) COD_MATERIAL, 
f1.INCLUIR, f2.TOTAL 
from quer1 f1 
full outer join Query2 f2 on f1.COD_RCA=f2.COD_RCA and f1.COD_MATERIAL=f2.COD_MATERIAL
```